# $.ajax not working in chrome and firefox but is working in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following code. It works fine in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox. There is no error displayed. It just doesn't get the value entered. Can someone help me fix the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
File 'main.php'
---------------

<tr>
<td width="11%" class="style171"></td>
<td width="55%" bgcolor="#A8D3FF" class="style171"><strong>APPROVE</strong></td>
<td width="16%" bgcolor="#A8D3FF" align="center"><input type="radio" name="approve" id="approve" value="1" <?php if ($approve== '1') echo "checked"; ?> /></td>
<td width="18%"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="11%" class="style171"></td>
<td class="style171" bgcolor="#A8D3FF"><strong>NOT APPROVE</strong></td>
<td bgcolor="#A8D3FF" align="center"><input type="radio" name="approve" id="approve" value="2" onClick="processForm()" <?php if ($approve== '2') echo "checked"; ?> /></td>
<td width="18%"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="11%" class="style171"></td>
<td colspan="2" align="left"><div id="div_data"></div></td>
<td width="18%"></td>
</tr>


<script type="text/javascript">

function processForm() 
{   
    var val = 0;

    if(window.document.getElementById('approve').checked)
        var val = 1;

    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'not_approved.php',
        data: "value="+val,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#div_data").html(html);
        }
    } );
}

</script>


File 'not_approved.php'
-----------------------

<form id="formt" name="formt" method="post" action="">
  <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#D8EEFE">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><table width="100%" border="1" bordercolor="#33CCFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="style2">
              <td align="left"><font color="#FF0000">*</font> Enter your comments here.
                <table width="430" border="0">
                  <tr class="style2">
                    <td width="10" align="left" valign="top"></td>
                    <td width="410" colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $comment; ?></textarea></td>          
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
            function processForm() 
            {   
                var val = 0;

                if(window.document.getElementById('approve').checked)
                    var val = 1;

                $.ajax( {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'not_approved.php',
                    data: {value:val},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#div_data").html(html);
                    }
                } );
            }

            </script>
```

** The data filed is changed **

Comment: I've tried it but still doesn't work. It displayed 'Notice: Undefined index: fieldname'

Comment: But I can't see the 'fieldname' in your code.So can you please provide the complete code with html

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data in wrong way do as below

```
data: "{'value':"+val+"}",
```

and if the value is in string then

```
data: "{'value':'"+val+"'}",
```

or

```
data: JSON.stringify({value:val})
```

Comment: I tried 'data: JSON.stringify({value:val})' but it doesn't work in IE. The other two works in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox. I got this error 'Notice: Undefined index: fieldname'.

Answer (score 0):

Your data variable must not be in string format because its a variable name. You should do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function processForm() 
{   
    var val = 0;

    if(window.document.getElementById('approve').checked)
        var val = 1;

    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'not_approved.php',
        data: {
               value: val,
              }
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#div_data").html(html);
        }
    } );
}

</script>
```

Here your script variable val value assigned to value variable and for assigning we use colon here ':' instead of = in AJAX. In server side the catching variable must also be of same name i.e value.

Comment: remove the line `cache:false` and then try.